# Stop and restart CoreAudio daemon under '_coreaudiod' user and not under root

Tags: c++, macos, core-audio, root, daemon

I am developing an app which needs to have exclusive access to the USB sound device. I found out that when the music is playing using this device then sometimes it is not possible to get access. So I need to stop and restart CoreAudio daemon.
I am using this piece of code (below) to get it work. But the problem is that after coreaudiod is stopped I can run it only under root user. By default it is ran under `_coreaudiod` user. **How can I run it under `_coreaudiod` user as it's done by the OS?**

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CFDictionary.h>
#include <Security/Authorization.h>

class ScopedAudioServiceStopper
{
public:
    ScopedAudioServiceStopper();
    ~ScopedAudioServiceStopper();
    void stop();

private:
    void start();

private:
    AuthorizationRef m_authorizationRef;
    CFDictionaryRef m_coreAudiodDictionary;
};
ScopedAudioServiceStopper::~ScopedAudioServiceStopper()
{
    start();
    if (m_coreAudiodDictionary)
            CFRelease(m_coreAudiodDictionary);
    if (m_authorizationRef)
            AuthorizationFree(m_authorizationRef, kAuthorizationFlagDestroyRights);
}

void ScopedAudioServiceStopper::stop()
{
    m_coreAudiodDictionary = SMJobCopyDictionary(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, CFSTR("com.apple.audio.coreaudiod"));
    if (!m_coreAudiodDictionary) //means daemon is not started
            return;

    if (errAuthorizationSuccess != AuthorizationCreate(nullptr, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, &m_authorizationRef)) {
            m_authorizationRef = nullptr;
            return;
    }

    AuthorizationItem authItem          = { kSMRightModifySystemDaemons, 0, nullptr, 0 };
    AuthorizationRights authRights  = { 1, &authItem };
    AuthorizationFlags flags                =   kAuthorizationFlagDefaults                          |
                                                                            kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed        |
                                                                            kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize                  |
                                                                            kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;
    // Obtain the right to install our privileged helper tool (kSMRightModifySystemDaemons).
    if (errAuthorizationSuccess != AuthorizationCopyRights(m_authorizationRef, &authRights, kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, flags, nullptr)) {
            m_authorizationRef = nullptr;
            return;
    }

    CFErrorRef  cfError;
    if (!SMJobRemove(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, CFSTR("com.apple.audio.coreaudiod"), m_authorizationRef, TRUE, &cfError)) {
            CFRelease(cfError);
    }
}

void ScopedAudioServiceStopper::start()
{
    if (!m_authorizationRef || !m_coreAudiodDictionary)
            return;

    CFErrorRef  cfError;
    if (!SMJobSubmit(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, m_coreAudiodDictionary, m_authorizationRef, &cfError)) {
            CFRelease(cfError);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the user is listening to music on the device are you sure they'd want you to forcibly stop it? It seems that displaying an alert requesting their action would be better.

Comment: killing coreaudiod just to have an exclusive access to the audio looks horribly bad, IMHO.  Have you played with the "Hog mode" ?  This looks design for that.